# Count De ID Filtrado por Data

Tags: sql

Preciso criar um SELECT filtrando por data (dia/mês/ano), onde me retorne a quantidade total de ID por determinado dia.

```
SELECT COUNT(ID), DATA_CAD FROM CADASTRO_ID_PESSOAS WITH(NOLOCK)
GROUP BY ID
```

Segue exemplo da tabela que tenho de retorno:

```
ID      DATA_CADASTRO
2896012 2021-01-15 11:25:45.113
2896013 2021-01-15 11:25:45.660
576629  2021-10-03 13:18:45.063
576630  2021-10-03 13:18:47.097
576668  2021-01-10 13:20:30.357
576669  2021-10-10 13:20:36.730
```

Exemplo de retorno como preciso:

```
ID      DATA_CADASTRO
2       2021-01-15
2       2021-10-03
1       2021-01-10
1       2021-10-10
```

Answer (score 0):

Uma maneira de resolver o problema seria agrupando os valores por data e fazendo  o count deste agrupamento. Ela é uma das funções de agregação do SQL.

```
SELECT COUNT(ID), DATA_CAD 
FROM CADASTRO_ID_PESSOAS
GROUP BY data_cad
```

A cláusula `GROUP BY` vai agrupar linhas baseado em um critério entre elas.

Segundo o padrão [`ANSI SQL`](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/sql-in-a/9780596155322/ch04s02.html), não é necessário utilizar a cláusula `GROUP BY` ou `HAVING` se o comando de agregação é o único valor do `SELECT`.

Todas as funções de agregação, exceto `COUNT(*)`, ignorarão valores `NULL` ao calcular seus resultados.

Answer (score 0):

*"retorne a quantidade total de ID por determinado dia"*

A sua pergunta já "se reponsde", o "total" consegue obter com `COUNT` e o "por determinado dia" é obtido usando `GROUP BY`, ou seja, "agrupe por data e calcule".

A resposta do @Danizavtz já ilustra isso, mas há um detalhe ai, como no seu exempo há data/hora, seu campo deve ser do tipo DATETIME, logo não adianta só agrupar, é preciso agrupar **apenas** pela data, logo é preciso adicionar ai a função `DATE`, assim:

```
SELECT COUNT(ID), 
       DATE(DATA_CADASTRO) 
  FROM CADASTRO_ID_PESSOAS
 GROUP BY DATE(DATA_CADASTRO);
```

Veja aqui um exemplo funcionando, e também a query sem o `DATE` que acaba não agrupando por data, mas por data/hora: [https://www.db-fiddle.com/](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gaXbmLq1sg7BPHc68kyqDP/0)